# Python : How to populate a column value to new column in another dataframe on comparing other column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, merge

Have got two dataframe

**df**

```
Store   Sku     Fixture
11      AA      Product
12      BB      Tier
```

**df1**

```
Store   Sku     Bit
11      AA      1
11      AA      2
12      CC      1
12      CC      2
12      CC      3
```

So, comparing the 'Store' column from dataframes, need to populate 'Fixture' column in df1 from df.
**Expected Output:**

```
Store   Sku     Bit     Fixture
11      AA      1       Product
11      AA      2       Product
12      CC      1       Tier
12      CC      2       Tier
12      CC      3       Tier
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are using dataframes as a relational database. If you are familiar with SQL, you will find [this documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html) useful.

Joining can be achieved either using `Series.map` or `merge`.

**Option 1: map**

First, build a dictionary holding the relation used for the mapping:

```
map_dict = df.set_index('Store')['Fixture'].to_dict()
```

`set_index` uses a column as row labels. By default, it does not modify the original `DataFrame`.

Then, we use this dict for a mapping of the 'Store' `Series`, and append the output to `df1`:

```
df1['Fixture'] = df1['Store'].map(map_dict)
```

**Option 2: `merge`**

You can perform a join of the two `DataFrame`s using merge. First, we get rid of the 'Sku' column of `df`, so we do not have issues with column names, and then perform the join:

```
joined = pd.merge(df1, df[['Store', 'Fixture']], on='Store')
```

If you don't get rid of `df`'s 'Sku' column, you will end up having an 'Sku_x' column from `df1` and a 'Sku_y' column from `df`.